# IONIC 3 filePath (native path) issue in case of PDF or DOC files

Tags: javascript, android, ionic3, angular5

I am trying to choose pdf of doc files using fileChooser plugin of IONIC 3 and I am getting the response like this

***content://com.coloros.filemanager/file_share/storage/emulated/0/documents/certificatenew.pdf***

then I am trying to get the native path in android devices using filePath plugin of IONIC 3 but I am  getting an error like this

***column '_data' does not exist***

I am getting this issue in Android Naugat and Oreo. Also, getting the native path of the image file using the same process, working just fine.

The following is the part of the code,

.......

```
        this.fileChooser.open().then((url) => {

          this.filePath.resolveNativePath(url)
            .then(filePath => {

              let currentPath = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
              let currentName = filePath.split('/')[filePath.split('/').length - 1];
              let fileext = currentName.split(".").pop();
              var d = new Date(),
                n = d.getTime(),
                newFileName = n + '.' + fileext;
```

.......

Can anyone tell me what to do? and what is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working for me,

```
      this.fileChooser.open()
      .then(
        uri => {
          this.filePath.resolveNativePath(uri)
            .then(file => {
              this.fileDir = file;
              this.fileName = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
      )
      .catch(error => {
        this.showError(error);
      });
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But same error

column '_data' does not exist

Actually, I am getting the error in the .catch err part of
this.filePath.resolveNativePath(uri) method.

I think that means the file path plugin giving error while trying to get the native path of pdf or doc files from the Android devices. And as I said before this error is coming only in nougat and oreo versions. The previous versions are working fine

Comment: did anyone get solution ?